# passport.socketio & client side connect/reconnect only when reboot server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, passport.js, passport.socketio

I've got a real time app that works fine with express+passportJS and without socket authentication.
When I add passport.socketio, my problem is that **sockets will only connect when I reboot the server...**

I've got passportjs & passport.socketio on the server and on the client side I've got angularjs with [btford.socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io):

```
angular.module('Socket', ['btford.socket-io'])

    .factory('socket',['socketFactory', function(socketFactory){
        var myIoSocket = io.connect("http://192.168.0.7:8080");

        mySocket = socketFactory({
            ioSocket: myIoSocket
        });

        return mySocket;
    }]);
```

When a user logs in, I'm doing `socket.connect();`.
This doesn't seem to be doing anything on the server side, I'm not seeing any logs...

Here's the implementation, as per the tutorial, of passport.socketio

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
var passportSocketIo = require("passport.socketio");

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    secret:       'secret',
    store:        sessionStore,
    success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,
    fail:         onAuthorizeFail,
}));

function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept){
    log.debug('successful connection to socket.io');
    return accept();
}

function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept){
    log.debug('unsuccessful connection to socket.io');
    if(error){
        throw new Error(message);
    }

    return accept(new Error(message));
}
```

The weird thing is, **when I restart the server, I can see a lot of log messages showing that all sockets I tried to connect now actually connect**.

And then it seems to let user exchange over socket and work as expected.

Anyone knows what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client opens the page the client will connect then handshake is initialized. Then the server check the authentication and forces to disconnect. Then the server doesn't check the authentication(doesn't initialize handshake) for the same socket connection. You have to FORCE a new connection from the client.

```
socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, {forceNew: true});
```

Your code

```
var myIoSocket = io.connect("http://192.168.0.7:8080",{forceNew: true});
```

I had the same problem, this solved my issue. If you force a new connection I hope all its previous event listeners will be lost. You have to add the event listeners again.